# Where are PC's NIC settings saved (i.e. custom MAC or power management options)?

Tags: network-adapter

Recently i learned how to enable and use WoL, but some details about it's underlying mechanisms are still mystery for me.

In [this answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/191854/does-wake-on-lan-wol-depend-on-hardware-or-the-operating-system) was said, that WoL is OS independent technology, and it seems to be correct regardless the process of powering machine up, but as i understood you can not setup WoL without any operating system. Enabling Waking on PCI (or whatever option name in your BIOS) was not enough for me. 
In my case i additionally used  Windows's device manager to enable Wake on NIC with magic packet only.
[image: wol settings in Windows OS]

There are more options on "Advanced" tab allowing me to change MAC address of interface. I changed MAC address and checked if WoL will be triggered with old MAC or new one. And it worked with MAC i had set using device manager.

[image: changing MAC]

So the question is: where are such settings of NIC saved? Is there any nvram inside of NIC? I suppose i should see my custom MAC if i will boot some other OS on my machine.

Also i do not understand how NIC finds a subsequence of MAC address repeated 6 times inside of so called "Magic packet". Main CPU does not seem to be work, so there should be some other processing unit comparing frame's payload with currently set MAC. Maybe my assumptions are wrong but i would like to clarify this.

PS Interesting fact: If WoL was set up in Windows, but disabled in BIOS, it starts working immediately after enabling "Wake on PCI" option in BIOS. But if WoL was set up in both Windows and BIOS, it does not stop working when i disable "Wake on PCI" ubtil i boot to windows. Was checked twice.

Comment: I think you are edging around the question "how intelligent is my nic?" For the most part, NICs perform programmed IO, so the CPU does much of the work, but yes, the NIC does have specialized hardware to handle many network advanced functions including WOL. As for your question on settings, some will be stored on the device itself in eprom, or may be driver configuration parameters (especially in the case of powermanagement), set at kernel load. The better the nic, the more hardware driven it will be. see more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller

Comment: Also, note that WOL recieves network signal and handles it in the NIC hardware, and then raises an IRQ to inform the system that it should change power states. This request is handled by the CPU, but the OS is responsible for actually changing state. even when asleep, the OS can listen for changes via the Advanced Configuration and Power Interface, a low level interface to bios power management functions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface